# Auto-tab between input fields with some having labels

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to build a "Jumble" style game. I want to have single character input fields with some having circles overlayed in them. I also want the user to be able to auto-tab to the next input field after filling out the input field. Here's the fields:

```
   <form id="jumble_word">
    <label><input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1"></label>
    <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
    <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
    <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
    <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
    <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
    <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
  </form>
```

Here's the JQUERY that I found that auto-tabs. However it doesn't auto-tab on the first input, and after some research, I understand that .next() only works with siblings.

```
$(":input").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).next(':input').focus();
  }
});
```

I'm using the label tag to overlay the circle. Here's the CSS

```
input[type=text] {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 36px;
  z-index: 1 !important;
}
    
label {
  position: relative;
}

label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: -34px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url("jumble.svg") center / contain no-repeat;
}
```

How can I change the jquery to have it auto-tab, regardless if an input field is surrounded by a label tag?

Comment: Try `$(this).next('input').focus()` or `$(this).next('.inputs').focus()`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: Why do you only have one set of labels? Also, why is the input nested in the first set of labels? That's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why your script is not working for `.next()`. There may be other elements or something blocking your script. I tested with the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#jumble_word > input").not(":last").keyup(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
      $(this).next("input").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.inputs {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 36px;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="jumble_word">
  <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input class="inputs round" type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
  <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1">
</form>
```

This worked as expected. Typing a letter into a Field causes it to focus on the next element.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I hadn't thought about styling the input field and kept trying to make an overlay work. Much appreciated!